# Ruby modify array items and return full array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have this code here

```
string.split(/(\w{1,}=)/).each_slice(1).map { |i| items << i }

items.map! do |i|
    i = i << str if i.to_s =~ /\w{1,}=/
end

puts items*''
```

And I want to modify certain items in the array based on regex, then return the full array with the modified items in it. This only returns the modified items. How do I achieve what I'm looking for?

EDIT: Ok, so say I'm trying to split a link using this regex:

> page.php?site=blah&id=1

The link is split and added to the array which now contains

> page.php?
>
> site=
>
> blah&
>
> id=
>
> 1

What I want to do is append some value to the end of the elements ending with a =. This way, when I return the modified array as a string it would output like this:

> page.php?site=(newval)&id=(newval)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please supply a sample input string and your expected output. When you have a question about code that isn't working right, we need to be able to replicate what you're seeing, and we need to be able to work from the same set of data. Please see "[ask]".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing number in URL after matching substring pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089533/replacing-number-in-url-after-matching-substring-pattern). This question is nearly identical and in your case the [`URI` Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33089828/1978251) is the best way to go.

Comment: `items = string.split(/(\w{1,}=)/)` and no  `.each_slice(1).map...` silliness.

Answer (score 1):

You have several undefined variables in your example, which is very sloppy.

1. `each_slice(1)` is equivalent to `each()`, so it's not clear why you are using `each_slice(1)`.  In any case, both `each()` and `map()` step through the items in an Array one by one, but each() returns the original Array unchanged. On the other hand, you use `map()` when you want to create a new Array that contains changes to the items.
2. In the regex `/\w{1,}/`, there is a shortcut for the quantifier `{1, }`, and it's: `+`, so most people would write the regex as `/\w+/`, where `+` means `1 or more`.
3. > I want to modify certain items in the array based on regex, then
   >   return the full array with the modified items in it.

Here is an example:

```
results = [1, 2, 3].map do |num|
  if num == 2
    num + 4
  else
    num - 1
  end
end

p results

--output:--
[0, 6, 2]
```

Your current attempt with `map()` doesn't return anything if the conditional fails.  Note how the example above returns something both when the condition fails AND when the condition succeeds. `map()` replaces an item with whatever is returned for that item.

Now look at this example:

```
results = [1, 2, 3].map do |num|
  if num == 2
    num + 4
  end
end

p results

--output:--
[nil, 6, nil]
```

If you don't return something for an item, then `map()` will use `nil` for that item. In the example, if the condition `num == 2` is true then `num+4` is returned--but if `num == 2` is false, nothing is returned.

**Edit:**

```
words = %w[
  page.php?
  site=
  blah&
  id=
  1
]    #=> words = ["page.php?", "site=", "blah&", "id=", "1"]

suffix = 'hello'

results = words.map do |word|
  if word.end_with?('=')   
    "#{word}#{suffix}"
  else
    word
  end
end

p results

--output:--
["page.php?", "site=hello", "blah&", "id=hello", "1"]
```

Comment: I added further explanation in my OP for clarity.

Comment: @user3674736, See the bottom of my post for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing a URL with a regex, have you considered using the [addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) gem?

```
require 'addressable/uri'

uri = Addressable::URI.parse('page.php?site=blah&id=1&bar')
uri.query_values = uri.query_values.map do |k, v| 
  [k, v.is_a?(String) ? v << 'foo' : v] 
end
puts uri.to_s # => page.php?site=blahfoo&id=1foo&bar
```

This won't handle very complex query parameters (it will just pass them through).

You can use `respond_to? :sub!` and `v.sub! /$/, 'foo'` instead of checking types if that makes you uneasy. (I wouldn't use `:<<` or `:concat` because those are valid methods for Arrays.)